# How to use multisampling on Direct x12

Tags: c++, directx-12

I have a question as to how to use multisample anti-aliasing (MSAA) on Direct x 12. I was unable to find an example on the web.

What I've seen around is that is not possible to directly enable MSAA on the swap chain. A separate multi-sampled texture needs to be used for rendering and after resolved on the swap chain.

But how to properly create a multi-sampled render target texture?

How to resolve a MSAA texture to screen?

Comment: See the answer to this stack overflow question [Creating a swap chain with MSAA fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110699/creating-a-swap-chain-with-msaa-fails) which has some links to additional material and see the answer to this posting, https://www.braynzarsoft.net/viewquestion/q33526-adding-msaa-in-dx12

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what i am looking for.

Comment: When you have a code sample that works, could you post an answer to your question that contains the source code along with some explanation as to why it works?

Comment: I will for sure :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this sample: [SimpleMSAA12](https://github.com/Microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/UWPSamples/IntroGraphics/SimpleMSAA_UWP12)

And this tutorial for [DirectX Tool Kit for DX12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Simple-rendering#multisampling)

Comment: The first link 404's now unfortunately

Comment: Sorry, minor repo reorganization. Fixed